# how to give priority to particular record in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table:

```
id     name    location
1      aaa     home
1      aaa     village
1      aaa     office
2      bbb     village
2      bbb     office
3      ccc     home
3      ccc     office
```

When I write a query, I should get single record for each
having precedence home > office > village

Output:

```
1 aaa home
2 bbb office
3 ccc home
```

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can use a group by:

```
SELECT 
   t.id, 
   t.name, 
   min( t.location ) keep (dense_rank first order by CASE location
                                                     WHEN 'home' THEN  1
                                                     WHEN 'office' THEN 2
                                                     WHEN 'village' THEN 3
                                                     ELSE  4
                                                     END
                            ) as location
FROM your_table t
GROUP BY 
   t.id, 
   t.name;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `row_number()` to assign each row a number in a given order per ID. Use a `CASE` to define the order by location.

```
SELECT x.id,
       x.name,
       x.location
       FROM (SELECT t.id,
                    t.name,
                    t.location,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY t.id
                                       ORDER BY CASE location
                                                  WHEN 'home' THEN
                                                    1
                                                  WHEN 'office' THEN
                                                    2
                                                  WHEN 'village' THEN
                                                    3
                                                  ELSE
                                                    4
                                                END)
                    FROM elbat) x
       WHERE x.rn = 1;
```

Note: If the locations are only exactly the given three, than the `CASE` isn't needed, as they coincidentally already have the wanted order when sorted lexicographically. But I assume that was just an example and the coincidence might not be given in the real data.